# Underfull \hbox severe issues

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I relaize this has been posted before but I just can't understand the nature of the problem, I hope some of you can help me with this. This is my code from line 99-174. Compiler errors are below the code.

```
\[
A_C = \begin{bmatrix}1 && 0 && -1 \\ -1 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1\end{bmatrix}
\] \newline
\section{Aufgabe}
Nutzen wie in der Aufgabenstellung vorrausgesetzt die Definition der Differenzierbarkeit:
\[
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y) - f(x,y) - f'(x,y)(\delta x,\delta y)}{\sqrt{(\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2)}}
\] \newline
Betrachten wir zun\"achst den Z\"ahler:
\[
f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y) - f(x,y) - f'(x,y)(\delta x,\delta y) 
\] \newline
\\
\begin{multline*}
= \begin{pmatrix} y + \delta y - (x+\delta x)^2\\y+\delta y\\x+\delta x\end{pmatrix} \\
- \begin{pmatrix} y-x^2\\y\\x\end{pmatrix} \\
- \begin{pmatrix} -2x && 1\\0 && 1\\1 && 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \delta x\\\delta y\end{pmatrix} 
\end{multline*}
\begin{multline*}
= \begin{pmatrix} -x^2 - 2x \delta x - (\delta x)^2 + y + \delta y \\y+\delta y\\x+\delta x\end{pmatrix} \\
- \begin{pmatrix} y-x^2\\y\\x\end{pmatrix} \\
- \begin{pmatrix} -2x \delta x + \delta y\\\delta y\\\delta x\end{pmatrix}  
\end{multline*}
\[
= \begin{pmatrix} -2\delta x - (\delta x)^2 + \delta y \\ \delta y \\ \delta x \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} -2x\delta x + \delta y \\ \delta y \\ \delta x\end{pmatrix} 
\] \newline
\[
= \begin{pmatrix} -(\delta x)^2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\]
Betrachtung von beiden f\"uhrt uns nun auf:
\[
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\begin{pmatrix}-(\frac{(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}} \\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
\]
Da $\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)} 0 = 0$, betrachten wir nur den Grenzwert der 1. Komponente, bzw. zunächst nur den Zähler $(\delta x)^2$
Stellen wir zuerst fest:
\[
-(\delta x)^2 \le 0 \ge -(\delta y)^2 \Rightarrow -(\delta x)^2 \le ((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) 
\] \newline
Sowie
\[
-((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) \le -(\delta x)^2
\] \newline
Also
\[
-((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) \le -(\delta x)^2 \le ((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) 
\] \newline 
Daraus folgt für den gesuchten Grenzwert: \newline 
\[
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{-((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2)}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\] \newline 
\[
\le
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{-(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\] \newline 
\[
\le
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2)}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\] \newline 
Durch Anwendung der Potenzregeln folgt:
\[
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}-\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}
\le
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{-(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\le
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}
\] 
Da $(\delta x) ^2 und (\delta y) ^2 beide alleine gegen 0 gehen muss die Summe der beiden, und die Wurzel der Summe natürlich auch gegen 0 gehen. Daraus folgt:
\[
0
\le
\lim\limits_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{-(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\le
0
\] \newline
Der Grenzwert muss somit auch gegen 0 streben (Sandwich theorem).
Somit strebt der $\vec{Fehler}$ schneller als linear gegen 0, also ist unsere Funktion diff'bar mit der gegebenen Ableitung.
```

## Compiler errors:

```
(...)

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 101--102

[3]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 112--114


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 112--114


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 117--118


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 120--121


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 123--124


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 126--127


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 129--130


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 132--133


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 153--155

[4]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 157--158


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 161--162


! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.174 \[

?
```

Comment: When you have several lines of equations after one another, you may want to use the `gather` or `align` environments from the `amsmath` package, rather than multiple `\[ ... \]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is using `\newline` that should be used rarely, if ever.

You also have consecutive display environments, which are not the best thing to do. Here's a proposal, which also corrects some space wasting construction you're using.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
A_C = \begin{bmatrix}1 && 0 && -1 \\ -1 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1\end{bmatrix}
\]

\section{Aufgabe}
Nutzen wie in der Aufgabenstellung vorrausgesetzt die Definition der
Differenzierbarkeit:
\[
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}
  \frac{f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y) - f(x,y) - f'(x,y)(\delta x,\delta y)}
       {\sqrt{(\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2)}}
\]
Betrachten wir zun\"achst den Z\"ahler:
\begin{align*}
&f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y) - f(x,y) - f'(x,y)(\delta x,\delta y) 
\\
&\qquad= \begin{pmatrix} y + \delta y - (x+\delta x)^2\\y+\delta y\\x+\delta x\end{pmatrix}
  - \begin{pmatrix} y-x^2\\y\\x\end{pmatrix}
  - \begin{pmatrix} -2x && 1\\0 && 1\\1 && 0\end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix} \delta x\\\delta y\end{pmatrix} 
\\
&\qquad= \begin{pmatrix}
     -x^2 - 2x \delta x - (\delta x)^2 + y + \delta y \\
     y+\delta y\\
     x+\delta x
  \end{pmatrix}
- \begin{pmatrix} y-x^2\\y\\x\end{pmatrix}
- \begin{pmatrix} -2x \delta x + \delta y\\\delta y\\\delta x\end{pmatrix}  
\\
&\qquad= \begin{pmatrix}
    -2\delta x - (\delta x)^2 + \delta y \\
    \delta y \\
    \delta x
  \end{pmatrix} 
- \begin{pmatrix} -2x\delta x + \delta y \\ \delta y \\ \delta x\end{pmatrix} 
\\
&\qquad= \begin{pmatrix} -(\delta x)^2 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Betrachtung von beiden f\"uhrt uns nun auf:
\[
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}
  \begin{pmatrix}-\dfrac{(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}} \\0\\0\end{pmatrix}
\]
Da $\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)} 0 = 0$, betrachten wir nur den Grenzwert 
der 1. Komponente, bzw. zunächst nur den Zähler $(\delta x)^2$ Stellen wir zuerst fest:
\[
-(\delta x)^2 \le 0 \ge -(\delta y)^2 \Rightarrow -(\delta x)^2 \le ((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) 
\]
Sowie
\[
-((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) \le -(\delta x)^2
\]
Also
\[
-((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) \le -(\delta x)^2 \le ((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2) 
\]
Daraus folgt für den gesuchten Grenzwert:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}
  \frac{-((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2)}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
&\le
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}
   \frac{-(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\\
&\le
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}
  \frac{((\delta x)^2 + (\delta y)^2)}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\end{align*}
Durch Anwendung der Potenzregeln folgt:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}-\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}
&\le
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{-(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\\
&\le
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}
\end{align*}
Da $(\delta x) ^2$ und $(\delta y) ^2$ beide alleine gegen $0$ gehen muss die Summe der beiden, 
und die Wurzel der Summe natürlich auch gegen $0$ gehen. Daraus folgt:
\[
0
\le
\lim_{(\delta x,\delta y) \rightarrow (0,0)}
  \frac{-(\delta x)^2}{\sqrt{\delta x ^2 + \delta y ^2}}
\le
0
\]
Der Grenzwert muss somit auch gegen $0$ streben (Sandwich theorem). Somit strebt der 
Fehler Vektor schneller als linear gegen $0$, also ist unsere Funktion diff'bar mit der 
gegebenen Ableitung.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\lim\limits` is superfluous in display math mode and `\lim` suffices. In inline math it's better to avoid it. Actually, in the document you use it for stating an obvious fact, I would remove it.

Comment: Copying your code fixed the compiling issues, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `\newline` and the `\\`. And that are not errors but warnings.
Use always

```
\[
...
\]
\[
...
\]
```

or

```
\[
...
\]
%
\[
...
\]
```

`\[...\]` is an own paragraph!

Comment: It may be warnings, but the .tex file is not compiling. What do?

Comment: underfull boxes are only warnings. If you get an error is depends to something different.